# WCF Per Call service disposing

Tags: c#, wcf

Let's suppose that service :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    int RetVal();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private int _counter;
    public int RetVal()
    {
        _counter++;
        return _counter;
    }
}
```

So my question is about this service lifetime and when it gets disposed. As I know it will be disposed once the method calls return.

Comment: The service should create a new instance for every call (hence PerCall).
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per

Comment: So I don't need to close the proxy and let it done by the GC